# Vue.js: Reactively update a component on a click

Tags: javascript, vue.js, reactive-programming

I have a component for adding/deleting an item to/from favorites. It works perfectly fine but a user cannot see whether he/she added the item to favorites or not (I show a star icon if the item is favorited and an empty one if not). How can I do this reactively? I want my icon to change its class if the user clicked on it.

Here is my code:

Component:

```
<template>
 <span :class="isFavorite
            ? 'mdi mdi-star favorite'
            : 'mdi mdi-star-outline'"
    class="favorite-item-icon"
    @click="isFavorite ? deleteFromFavoriteItems(itemId) : addToFavoriteItems(itemId)">
 </span>
</template>

<script>
 export default {
  import { mapGetters, mapActions } from 'vuex';

  props: ['itemId', 'isFavorite'],
  methods: {
    ...mapActions(['addToFavoriteItems', 'deleteFromFavoriteItems']),
  },
};
</script>
```

The component in v-for list of a parent component:

```
...
 <favorite-label :itemId="item.id" :isFavorite="item.is_favourite" />
...
```

In my store:

```
addToFavoriteItems({ commit }, itemId) {
  http
    .post(`${config.api}api/v1/items/favourite-save`, {
      item_id: itemId,
    });
deleteFromFavoriteItems({ commit }, itemId) {
  http
    .post(`${config.api}api/v1/items/favourite-delete`, {
      item_id: itemId,
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to assign the `item` from the server (after update) to the store, something like:

```
$post(..., { item_id: itemId }).then(function(response) {
  this.$store.commit('items/SET_ITEM', response.data)
})
```

Where the `items/SET_ITEM` mutation loops the items in the current array and updates the item if the `id` matches.

```
let itemToUpdate = this.items.forEach(function(i) {
  if (i.id === item.id) {
    i = item
  }
})
```

Then it should correctly mutate the store dispatching the prop update and causing the view to re-render with the new `isFavorite` calculation in place.

Alternatively, if the `itemId` that you're passing can be used, there's no reason for the server to change anything, just pass it along instead, like:

```
$post(..., { item_id: itemId }).then(function() {
  this.$store.commit('items/UPDATE_FAVORITE', { item: itemId })
})
```

And now you could just add a mutation that toggles the favorite, basically:

```
this.items.forEach(function(i) {
  if (i.id === item) {
      i.is_favorite = !i.is_favorite
  }
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggested solution. Unfortunately, it is still working as it did before. My icon doesn't change itself reactively, only after refresh. Is it possible to add some kind of a watcher?

Comment: Okay, I fixed this problem and now my icon updates itself reactively. However, this happens quite slow (approx. 2 sec). Is this any way to toggle icons faster? I think it is toggled as soon as my request gets the response and either add or remove item from favorites. But for UX this behaviour is a little bit slow... :(

Comment: @OlgaB You can perform the `commit` BEFORE the post request and use `.catch(error)` to roll it back if there's a problem